# Activate virtual environment and run python script on RPi startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, opencv

I am working on my project and using a raspberry pi 2 with raspbian OS. I followed the following link http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/ to install opencv and python on my pi.
     What I am trying to do is I want to activate my virtual environment automatically when the pi boots up and want to run a particular .py file on startup. What I have done so far is:

(i) I have created a .sh file and edited it as follows:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  # launcher.sh
  # navigate to home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home
  cd /
  cd home/pi/
  sudo source ~/.profile          (sourcing .profile)
  sudo workon cv                  (cv is my virtual environment)
  sudo python test_video.py       (test_video.py is .py file)
  cd /
```

(ii) To make it executable, I used the following command:

```
   chmod 755 launcher.sh
```

(iii) Then I tried launching my file using

```
   sh launcher.sh (launcher is filename)
```

When I ran this, I got the following errors:

```
   sudo: source: command not found
   sudo: workon: command not found
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test_video.py", line 4, in <module>
          import cv2
   ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Kindly help me out. I am trying to automatically activate my virtual environemt name 'cv' and want to run test_video.py file on startup.

Comment: https://aytacgenc.wordpress.com/2016/06/10/raspberry-pi-starting-with-script/ wrote about artice about this. This may help you.

Comment: What was the final shell line that you used in the end as I have exactly the same issue???

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems there:
1) you'll need to supply the full path to **source**
2) you'll need to supply the full path to **workon**
3) there's an error in line 4 of **test_video.py** (my best guess is that cv2 hasn't been installed (apt-get install ...)

I'm quite surprised the shell script ran: my experience was that I needed to supply the full path to the shell script. Simply typing its name from the same folder was insufficient.